# Displaying data with pagination - get whole data at once or get part for each page?

Tags: sql, performance, pagination, limit, offset

Which way is the best in case of performance if I want to display data with pagination? Should I download all data from the DB and then locally switch those parts depending on the current page or get the data from the DB part by part?

Firstly I was opting for the second option but I started wondering, found [this](https://dzone.com/articles/why-most-programmers-get-pagination-wrong) article and I'm lost now.

In my SQL queries, I'm using OFFSET and LIMIT attribute and since I'm also obtaining the last page of the pagination so the better option would be the first one as far as I understand? Important to notice is my database is quite small.

And the best one option would be to still use OFFSET but without reading last page or I'm wrong (in case of larger databases and improvement of performance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end, I implemented it just like the article says. Removed the "move to last page" button so it won't be forced to count all rows and anyway I got some of sorting features like ASC/DESC by particular columns so still if user want to go to the last page he can casually click this filter option and he will get the last elements but using as I said before ASC/DESC queries which I hope are faster than OFFSET.